# I updated angular application from 10 to 12 , it runs fine in development ,but when i build the application and host the files in cpanel , i get err

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

This error only occurs after I login successfully ,and this error does not let me enter to dashboard ,of my application.

I have tried changing aot : "true" in ts.config ,but it does not work.

[image]

Comment: it's a guess (that's why I put it as comment). Assuming that you don't have a variable named `bootstrap`, Bootstrap library seems to be missing. To understand why, you need to put much more debugging or console output